# SQL: have duplicates for each ID, I would like to keep the ID with site that is not blank

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID        Site
a         www.google.com
a         
b         www.qq.com
b         
c         www.hodes.com
.
.
.
```

I have a table like the one above, I'd like to extract the the site value is not blank, such as:

```
ID        Site
a         www.google.com
b         www.qq.com
c         www.hodes.com
```

Comment: be more specific. do you want to `select` non-null values or `update` the table?

Comment: be more specific. what do you want to do if you have an ID with a blank Site, but no non-blank site for that ID?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Site IS NOT NULL`?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do or what the problem is.  (Or why an *identifier* would be repeated.)

Comment: As I mentioned above, some IDs have two records on site. One has site name, while one is blank. I want to keep the record that is not blank. Besides, some IDs just have one record on site, so just keep the record that it has.

Comment: @vkp  For the IDs have two records, I want to select non-null value. But for IDs that just have one record, I just keep whatever the one they have

Answer (score 0):

`select * from table where Site <> '' or Site is not null` 
will work if the blank ones are ALWAYS duplicates.

otherwise

```
select max(id), max(site) from table group by id
```

Should be okay

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check if the content of the column site is null or not. In order to select the rows with content:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE SITE IS NOT NULL
```

Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null).

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  ID,
  max(if(trim(site) = '', null, site)) as site
from tbl
group by ID
;
```

You could substitute `GROUP_CONCAT` for max if more than one site per ID.

Comment: The method using Max(site), I think it what I want. Because for IDs that have just one record but blank, I also need to keep it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go on a limb and assume that you want to remove the empty rows from your database. If that's not the case, just move the where clause to a `Select` statement.

```
Delete from TableName where ISNULL(Site, '')=''
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must return one and only one record per id, then your code must 
cope with potential multiple records per id -- and you need the max() and group by .
I would suggest:

```
    Select id, max(site)
    from table_name
    where nvl(site,0) <> 0
    group by id
```

Else if you know that  you'd never encounter multiple records with the same id:

```
    Select id, site
    from table_name
    where nvl(site,0) <> 0
```

Comment: I think the method using Max is correct. May I know what 'nvl' means?